# Installing Jekyll theme complains "destination path './_theme_packages/_tmp' already exists and is not an empty directory."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm trying to install a Jekyll theme via

```
rake theme:install git="https://github.com/jekyllbootstrap/theme-the-program.git"
```

As instructed on [Jekyll Bootstrap's page here](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-theming.html).

However it complains

destination path './_theme_packages/_tmp' already exists and is not an empty directory.

The annoying thing is if I clobber this folder

```
sudo rm -rf _theme_packages
```

It will then give this error

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - ./_theme_packages/_tmp/manifest.yml
```

And if I run again, I get the first error.

So the install is way not idempotent which makes me think it wasn't really developed or tested well in the first place.

Is there any easy patch?

Jekyll 1.X. Possibly the problem - the theme says I need 2.x. [Researching this right now]

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the _tmp folder under _theme_packages folder and try it again.